# NHibernate , how to loop and get results ?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

In the NHibernate, how to loop and get results ? for example, how to get 'totalAmount' and 'MY_CODE' ?

```
var criteria = Session.CreateCriteria<MyClass>();
ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.ProjectionList();
projectionList.Add(Projections.RowCount(), "totalAmount");
projectionList.Add(Projections.GroupProperty("MY_CODE"));
criteria.SetProjection(projectionList);

var resultList = criteria.List();
// how to get 'totalAmount' and 'MY_CODE'
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"how to loop and get results" u can make:

```
 var total = 0;
 var code = "";
 foreach(var result in resultList)
 {
      total = result[0]; // or result["totalAmount"]
      code = result[1];  // or result["my_code"]
      //then do something with em
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong that query will return a list of `object[]`. So you need to do

```
int totalAmount = resultList[i][0];
string myCode= resultList[i][1];
```